# 'Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract' not found in shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Mysql4\Abstract.php

Tags: magento-1.8, localhost

I get an error when attempting to run my site on my localhost server.  I've done this many times in the past:  extract my site from git, point to my local copy of the database, configure localhost database in local.xml, and clear the 'var' directory to remove cache, sessions, etc.

However, now, I get the following error. Any clues to help my track down my configuration local hosting issue?

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract' not found in 
>   D:\Ampps...\shop\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Mysql4\Abstract.php on line 36

Note: the file path is edited (with ...) to obfuscate the website details.   And, the file definitely does exist at the path reported in the error message.

Comment: I got my localhost site working using a different branch from git.  I'll diagnose the differences between the branches and post the root cause of the error to share with all.

Answer (score 1):

You'd check your project files, it seems you're missing a core file: **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php**

You could download 1.8 package, and copy **app/code/core** folder into your project (maybe some other folders are needed, if other errors appear)

Comment: You use compiler or some other extension affecting the filesystem? The error is clear. You **must** have app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/ directory. Double check that (downloading 1.8 package should fix that).

Comment: The file does exist at both the path you described in your answer  app/code/core/Mage/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php  and at the path in the error message app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abtract.php   
The first thing I did was looked to see if the file existed.  I updated the question since I omitted that detail.

Comment: Just download 1.8, replace app/code/core, and check "git status"